# Unable saving an associative array using add_post_meta() function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, associative-array

I need to run an encryption function on each member of an associative array prior to it being saved to `wp_postmeta` table. My form allows dynamic add/delete of rows. I've been trying to get this to work using `array_walk()`.

This is how the form is configured:

```
<input type="text" id="z_my_data[][username]" name="z_my_data[0][username]">
<input type="text" id="z_my_data[][password]" name="z_my_data[0][password]">
```

This is ran on the 'save_post` action:

```
// Save encrypted data to post meta
if (isset($_POST['z_my_data'])) {  

    // Get posted form variables
    $my_data = $_POST['z_my_data'];

    // Encrypt each member of each row
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_data); $i++) {
        $cryptKey = $this->cryptKey;
        array_walk($my_data[strval($i)], create_function('&$val', 'global $cryptKey; $val = Crypto::encrypt($val, $cryptKey);'));
    }

    if ( ! add_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_data', $my_data, true ) ) { 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_data', $my_data);
    }

} else {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_data' );
}
```

I can see that the data is being encrypted. Here is a **`print_r($my_data)`** after the `for` loop:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => ®ØåÛâÏ0…"ë°?mË¤Ù
            [password] => xSFç„L¶·3z˜'J0ÖRÅÎj
        )

)
```

But the post meta key is not created and no error is generated. The meta key doesn't exist in the postmeta table, yet `add_post_meta()` returns false and the key/value is never added.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm not sure how to tell, but I think the [0] is a named key and not an index key. I say that because I can create more than one and delete the [0] element and the single element remaining still shows [1] using `print_r`.

Comment: In the conditional block `if ( ! add_post_meta....`, put an `else` condition and do something handle it.

Comment: @JeremyHarris `add_post_meta` returns false if it already exists. It returns true if the add is successful. Am I missing your point?

Comment: `But the post meta key is not created and no error is generated`....so clearly that `if` statement return false then. You have the `unique` argument set to true (last one), so you are probably running into a duplicate value. How do you want to handle that? Add an `else` condition and handle it :-)

Comment: @JeremyHarris You are right. The add fails and returns false, then the update fails too. But the add should have added the post meta. There are no duplicates. The postmeta table has only 9 rows so I can see them all. So... the add fails, what would I do next? It seems that $my_data isn't in the correct format, but I'm guessing.

Comment: `[0] is a named key` Because you are using `$my_data[strval($i)]`. Instead just use `$my_data[$i]` to create an indexed array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your `if ( ! add_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_data', $my_data, true ) ) {` you are using **`add_post_meta()`** function and last argument is set to **`true`**.
>   **It should be `false` instead**, because you are inserting an **`array`** and **NOT** a **`string`**. 
>   For this reason your **`if`** statement **is not working properly**.

Instead, your code should be *(as [**`add_post_meta`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/) last argument default value is **`false`**)*:

```
if ( ! add_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_data', $my_data ) ) { 
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_data', $my_data );
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use this:

```
if ( ( !empty( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_data' ) ) ) { 
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_data', $my_data );
}
```

---

References:

- [WordPress Code Reference - add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/)
- [WordPress Code Reference - update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)
- [WordPress Code Reference - get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

Comment: I think my two questions were related to the same problem. I understand now, thanks!